# incorrect symbols with gt summary output for continuous variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am a novice to R. I am using R studio with R 4.0.2 on a Windows 10 machine. I just used the gt summary package for the first time and attempted to recreate the output from one of the vignette examples:

```
library(gtsummary)
trial %>%
  select(age, marker, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd}",
    missing = "no"
  )
```

When I run the code chunk in within my R markdown document, the table output contains � instead of the ± symbol. For example:  Age  47 � 15. Additional libraries loaded include tidyverse and utf8.

When I knit it to an html document the correct symbol is used. Any ideas why it is not producing the correct symbol when running the code chunk within my R markdown document? I apologize in advance to all the hardcore programmers for my potential lack of correct form and choice of words in trying to describe this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a {gtsummary}, rather some kind of system encoding issue.  Can you run this code and let us know what you see?
`data.frame(symbol = "±") %>% gt::gt()`

Does this render correctly when running as a isolated code chunk? When it is knit?

Comment: You are correct. Same issue when I run the above code chunk  as isolated code chunk, renders correctly when knit to html. Thank you for troubleshooting!

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more assistance! Encoding is hard :|